# How to pass a JavaScript var into a Rails Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, camanjs

I'm looking to **pass a JavaScript variable into a Rails Controller**. The interesting part is that the variable is generated inside `Canman`, and I cannot use it (yet) outside of it.

This is probably just JavaScript and not necessarily related with Canman. But I'm just not sure what it is happening here.

The approach I'm following (but completely open if there is a better way) is to populate a hidden field with jQuery, just to access the data via params from the controller.

If possible (and if this is a good practice) I will like to avoid the form, and just call some JavaScript on click and then pass that variable to the controller.

---

View

```
= form_for @post do |form|
  = form.hidden_field :base64
  = form.submit
```

JavaScript

```
$('form').submit(function(event){

  Caman('#canvas', img, function() {
    var imageBase64 = this.toBase64();
    alert(imageBase64); // works fine
    $('#post_base64').val(imageBase64);
  });

  alert(imageBase64); // nothing
});
```

PostsController

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  raise '¯\_(ツ)_/¯'
  ...
end
```

post_params

```
=> {"base64"=>""}
```

---

Also, I read that an option could be to make an AJAX request. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with that, yet.

At some point, I tried with a text_area instead of a hidden_field. The text_area got populated with the right data. However, params never got the data. If I got back via the browser button, the data was in the text_area, and clicking on submit one more time, populates the params as expected.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `var imageBase64 = this.toBase64();` is local to the function. Your second alert can't see it. I don't know what Caman is. Use JQuery post instead. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. Remember to possibly turn off authenticity token checking. Also verify `$('#post_base64')` exists.

Comment: Thanks Chloe for explaining that! :D I have verified the existence via `alert($('#post_base64'));` It shows `1`. About `$.post`, that sound the right thing to do, but I'm having issues to implement it. Can you elaborate a little bit about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **Ajax**.

The goal was to send the value of a variable (a base64 image) to my rails controller, and once there, keep going just with Ruby.

At the end, I created a simple Ajax function to send data from my client (Image from browser) to my server (Rails Controller) via `params`

**save_canvas.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.save_canvas', function() {
  event.preventDefault()
  var base64Data = canvas.toDataURL('png')

  $.ajax({
    type:    "POST",
    url:     "http://localhost:3000/pictures/",
    data:    { image: base64Data },
    success: function(post){ console.log('success') },
    error:   function(post){ console.log(this) }
  })
})
```

**pictures_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(image: params[:image])
    @picture.save
    redirect_to @picture
  end
```

I got support to achieve this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376215/how-to-save-a-canvas-via-paperclip)