# How to save a Canvas via Paperclip

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, paperclip

I have been working with two approaches, but **the goal is just to save the canvas via Paperclip.**

**First approach**

> Canvas to Base64 and then add base64 to params with ajax

```
    $(document).on('click', '#save_canvas', function() {
      var base64Data = canvas.toDataURL()

      $.ajax({
        type:    "POST",
        url:     "pictures/",
        data:    { base64: base64Data },
        success: function(post){ console.log('success') },
        error:   function(post){ console.log(this) }
      })
    })
```

> Access params[:base64] via Paperclip.adapters_io

```
  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    # ...

    image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(params[:base64])
    image.original_filename = "canvas.png"

    @picture.image = image

    @picture.save
    redirect_to @picture
  end
```

I think this is not working, to start, because this is only including `base64` in params and missing all the other required params.

---

**Second approach**

> Canvas to Base64 and then manually (just to make it work and keep working from there) copy data from the console and paste it into a form field.

```
= link_to " Base64", "#", remote: true, onclick: "console.log(canvas.toDataURL('png'))" 
= form_for @picture, html: { multipart: true } do |form|
  = form.text_field :base64
  = form.submit
```

> Access params[:picture][:base64] via Paperclip.adapters_io

```
  def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)

    image = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(params[:picture][:base64])
    image.original_filename = "canvas.png"

    @picture.image = image

    @picture.save
    redirect_to @picture
  end
```

With this approach, I can save the canvas. But I found two issues:

1) I have to eliminate the copy/paste step.
2) Canvas can generate very long strings with more than 1 million characters (that's crazy) and form field is not allowing such a huge length.

**This is a Rails 4.2 project using Paperclip 4.3 and will be hosted on Heroku.**
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach should be the good one. The string created put the mime type at start, and paperclip can handle base64 string.

Example in one of our projects (working well)

```
 #in our coffeescript (own ajax method, no jquery, but same behavior)
 ajax("images",
  method: "post",
  data: {image: @state.src}
 ).then((result) =>
   console.log "yey"
 )

 #In the image_controller, to add an uploaded picture
 def create
   current_user.photos.new picture: params[:image]
 end
```

Our paperclip version is 4.3.3. We use it with Html5 File API, not canvas, but the output (base64) is exactly same format than the `Canvas#toDataUrl`, as long as we can display a preview in a src attribute of an image.

Comment: Thanks Yacine,  I just needed to fix my controller.

Comment: Hi Yacine, I have noticed that saving images this way is really slow, kind of 5x - 6x times slower. So, a picture rendered inside a 1000x1000px canvas, takes around 16s to 19s (localhost) to save it (pretty much all the time is to encode the image). Do you have an idea about how to improve this? Thanks!

Comment: Is it server or client side? I mean it's at the toDataURL part ? If yes, I sadly don't have any clues to fix it. 
Otherwise if it's server side, you can make a workaround, using base64 library to create a temporary file then use this tempfile into paperclip. Good luck !